# "Storey" or "storeyed" in this context

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Cambridge dictionary says:

> It's a normal **two storeyed** house.
>
> There is a **single-storeyed** extension on the back of the house.
>
> A **three-storey** house.

There is no hyphen in the first, and the use of **single-storeyed** and **three-storey** confused me.

Please explain.

Thank you.

Comment: Storeyed means "having storeys or floors". So the 3rd one seems incorrect to me. It could be "A house with three storeys." Other than that, I think the hyphen is optional. But I'm not sure as Cambridge dictionary is not likely to make a mistake.

Comment: Just check out in the Cambridge dictionary.

Comment: I'm not saying that you are quoting the dictionary wrong. I trust you :) . I'm just saying that what the dictionary says seems wrong to me (the third sentence)

Answer (score 2):

In theory, 'storeyed' is an adjective and 'storey' is a noun.

> It is a three-storeyed house.

'Storeyed' is describing the house.

As a compound adjective 'three-storeyed' would usually be considered to need a hyphen, but it's a rule that can be flexible, as we see in your example. 'Storeyed' is almost always going to be preceded by a number, so it is not as if there is much ambiguity to the meaning.

In practice, my experience is that 'storey' is used extremely commonly as both a noun and an adjective.

> It's a thirty-storey high-rise. (Adjective)
>
> The high-rise has thirty stories. (Noun)

In fact, I did not even realise that 'storeyed' was a word that existed in the context of the floors of buildings (in contrast to, say, "he had a storied past").

I think, therefore, the Cambridge dictionary is simply suggesting either version is acceptable. I'd add that 'storey' is a lot more common in the parts of the world I'm familiar with.

See examples [here](https://biv.com/article/2019/01/thirty-one-storey-office-tower-proposed-downtown-vancouver) (North American) and [here](https://www.meetingplacecommunications.com/the-yimby/2018/5/16/uoezrk5sl819akry2sw9th7my7r7hq) (British).

Perhaps 'thirty storey building' could be considered a noun phrase, in which case, 'storey' could be argued to still be a noun and not an adjective? Others are more qualified than me to say, and being part of a noun phrases does not remove an adjective's obligation to behave like an adjective. Whatever. In practice, the bottom line is that 'storeyed' is not common in my experience.